# Find the probability that two people will meet between 4pm and 5Pm

Tags: probability

We are given that no 1 person will wait for more than 15 minutes for the other person after arriving. I want the probability that they meet during that hour. They don't visit the meeting point again. 
My attempt:
Let $X, Y$ denote their arrival time respectively. Then, $X \sim U(0,60)$ and $Y \sim U(0,60)$.
We want $P(|X-Y|<15)$
$\large{P(|X-Y|<15)=P(X<Y+15)-P(X<Y-15)= \int_{0}^{45} \int_{0}^{y+15} \frac{1}{60^2}  dx dy - \int_{15}^{60} \int_{0}^{y-15} \frac{1}{60^2} dx dy= \frac{9}{32}}  $

I have seen the geometric method to solve this problem. My answer doesn't agree with that approach. Please tell me where and why, I'm wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Your $P(X<Y+15)$ is actually $P(X<Y+15<60)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. Isnt the restriction by 60 needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calculating the probabilities correctly. For instance, $$P(X < Y+15) = \int_0^{45}dy\int_{0}^{y+15}dx \frac{1}{60^2} + \int_{45}^{60}dy\int_0^{60}dx \frac{1}{60^2} $$

(Also you don't need to take integrals. Just sketch a square and sketch the region and find its area.)

Comment: Thank you so much.  You're right, I forgot to include the part where X arrives between 45 and 60 minutes.  I am learning double integrals so that's why I decided to see if I could do this problem without relying on geometry.